# Reading data from DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I read data from `DataGridView` in C#? I want to read the data appear in Table. How do I navigate through lines?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

something like

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGrid.Rows.Count; rows++)
{
     for (int col= 0; col < dataGrid.Rows[rows].Cells.Count; col++)
    {
        string value = dataGrid.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value.ToString();

    }
}
```

example without using index

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
{ 
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        string value = cell.Value.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing the type of a row or cell i.e. "DataGridViewRow" or "DataGridViewCell" respectively, you can simply write "var".

Comment: @kami if var is used, row.Cells throws an error because it thinks row is type object

Answer (score 10):

If you wish, you can also use the column names instead of column numbers.

For example, if you want to read data from DataGridView on the 4. row and the "Name" column.
It provides me a better understanding for which variable I am dealing with.

```
dataGridView.Rows[4].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Code Example : Reading data from DataGridView and storing it in an array**

```
int[,] n = new int[3, 19];
for (int i = 0; i < (StartDataView.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < StartDataView.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if(this.StartDataView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            try
            {
                n[i, j] = int.Parse(this.StartDataView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception Ee)
            { //get exception of "null"
                MessageBox.Show(Ee.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the try-catch in your example.  You should test to make sure the cell isn't null before parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[,] myGridData = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count,3];

int i = 0;

foreach(DataRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)

{

    myGridData[i][0] = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    myGridData[i][1] = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    myGridData[i][2] = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

    i++;
}
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void HighLightGridRows()
 {            
     Debugger.Launch();
     for (int i = 0; i < dtgvAppSettings.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
         String key = dtgvAppSettings.Rows[i].Cells["Key"].Value.ToString();
         if (key.ToLower().Contains("applicationpath") == true)
         {
             dtgvAppSettings.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
         }
     }
 }
```