# Reading from DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`filled with information from my SQL:
[image]

[Its only possible to click one complete row and not only a cell, shown in my picture]

I try some Code example from: [Reading data from DataGridView in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487839/how-can-i-read-data-from-datagridview-c) but it dosent work for my Problem.

I try this, because it seems good

```
dataGridView.Rows[MyIndex].Cells["MessageHeadline"].Value.ToString();
```

but i get an Error.

Now i want to take the Index (add with 1, because its start with 0) and if i press on a row, my program should take the information from my `DataGridView`and give it back.

Comment: `but i get an Error.` -What error?

Comment: if you can select only 1 row you can try `i = dataGridView.SelectedRow[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString()`. Then `i` will be 1.(from your pic).

Comment: @Acme "System.ArgumentException" in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: @Georgi It would work not clear, beacuse i need to take the Value directly from "MessageHeadline" or "MessageText" because i have some unvisible between them

Comment: Ok, then make it like you do `dataGridView.SelectedRow[0].Cells["MessageHeadline"].Value.ToString()` . I tried it with a button and it works. Please tell does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `CurrentRow` instead of `SelectedRow`. The selected row only perform if you have selected row from `RowHeader` or the `RowSelection` property is set `FullRowSelect`. But, CurrentRow is actually focused row. You can get value even you have selected only single cell.

```
dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["MessageHeadline"].Value.ToString()
```

Comment: Yep that seems to be better solution.

Comment: @Georgi   IMPORTANT: It only works if you go to your `DataGridView` and edit the `Name` of your Headers or you get a Exception and it dosen't work because it cant find "MessageHeadline" in your `DataGridView` !
@Nimesh: Work Great. Short and Clear! Nice :)

Comment: It is necessary to check is `CurrentRow` exists or it is null before reading data from gridview.

Comment: I have done this, so the User have to 'Update' first the `DataGridView` (fill it with all data). After this the User can read from it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Set the `SelectionMode` property of your datagridview to `CellSelect`. Now you will be able to select a cell itself.

And in `CellMouseClick` Event:

```
private void MyGridView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    string FullContent = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < MyGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        FullContent += MyGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString() + "^";
    }
    FullContent = FullContent.Substring(0, Content.Length - 1);
    string[] Content=FullContent.Split('^')
}
```

Now you can get each column content from Content array.
Like:

```
Content[0],Content[1],Content[2],etc.
```

For example, if you click the first row in your datagridview.
You can access the contents like:

```
FullContent;  //1^Test BGW 1^Test^All^12.05.2014^.....
```

Splitted contents:

```
Content[0];   //1
Content[1];   //Test BGW 1
Content[2];   //Test
Content[3];   //All
Content[4];   //12.05.2014
```

Comment: Would work, BUT not clearly what i want , because the "User" should be able to click only a full row and then it should give me all back i needed

Comment: Look to Nimesh, this example (read comments) is shorter and works great! Thanks for your Help :)

Answer (score 0):

just using the foreach loop can solve the problem.

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridStore.Rows)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());    //row.Cell[index Here!]
        }
```