# Read an specific cell of a datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I want to read the data in a specific cell of a datagrid, or be able to assign the cell value to a variable; 
Important note:
I am new to C#, I spend ours looking, Now I don’t have more time for research although the question is kind of idiotic for someone.  Sorry If I am violating any rule of this site, but I ran out of time and need an answer asp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading data from DataGridView in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487839/reading-data-from-datagridview-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487839/reading-data-from-datagridview-in-c-sharp) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

YOu can get the value like this :

```
string str=Gridview_name.Rows[row_index]["Column_name"].ToString();
```

Assigning value to a specific cell can do similar ways :

```
Gridview_name.Rows[row_index]["Column_name"] = value;
```

For more reference [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/442/how-to-get-the-values-of-selected-row-from-a-gridview-using-aspnet)

Comment: I have an error, says row_index does not exist in the current content!! a suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: Where row_index is an integer representing the index of row in gridview