# Export Datagridview To XML File C#

Tags: c#, excel, xml

I have a requirement where I need to export data from excel file that import to a 'datagridview' to a specified format 'xml'   firstly I fill to datagrid from excel and  save as Xml ,folowing this code

```
        namespace SAMPLE_
        {


            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();

                }
```

Here I am using Microsoft Office Interop Excel to import Excel file:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorlSheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange;

            int xlRow;
            string strfileName;

            openFilalog1.Filter = "Excel Office | *.xls; *.xlsx";
            openFilalog1.ShowDialog();
            strfileName = openFilalog1.FileName;


             if(strfileName != string.Empty)
            {

                xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strfileName);
                xlWorlSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets["SHEET1"];
                xlRange = xlWorlSheet.UsedRange;
                int i=0;
                for (xlRow = 2; xlRow <= xlRange.Rows.Count; xlRow++)
                {
                    if(xlRange.Cells[xlRow,2].Text != "")
                    {
                        i++;
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 1].Text, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 
                        2].Text,
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 3].Text, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 4].Text,
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 5].Text, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 6].Text,
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 7].Text, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 8].Text,
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 9].Text,xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 10].Text,
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 11].Text,xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 12].Text,
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 13].Text);

                    }

            }
                xlWorkBook.Close();
                xlApp.Quit();

            }
```

This is the button I use to export:

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        DataSet ds = (DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource;
                        SaveFilalog sfd = new SaveFilalog();
                        sfd.Filter = "SHEET1|*.xml";
                        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                ds.Tables[0].WriteXml(sfd.FileName);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {

                    }
                }


            }
```

Comment: I need to know the xml format.  Apparently the current write ds.Tables[0].WriteXml(sfd.FileName); is not the correct format.

Comment: so what is correct format ?

Comment: You have to tell me.  You said "to a specified format 'xml".  So what is the format?

Comment: This is the format that i want on the outpout xml:

`<rd>
        <id>column 1 cell 1</id>
        <name>column 2 cell 1</name>
        <last>column 3 cell 1</last>
        <phone>column 4 cell 1</phone>
<refF>
          <adresse>column 5 cell 1</adresse>
          <citie>column 6 cell 1</citie>
</refF>
          <age>column 7 cell 1</age>
<mp>
          <degree>column 8 cell 1</degree>
</mp>
          <dpa>column 9 cell 1</dpa>
</rd>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a datatable it would be something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("last", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("phone", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("adresse", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("citie", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("age", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("mp", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("dpa", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("New A", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("New B", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("New C", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("New D", typeof(string));
            for (xlRow = 2; xlRow <= xlRange.Rows.Count; xlRow++)
            {
                if (xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 2].Text != "")
                {

                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 1].Text, 
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow,2].Text,
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 3].Text, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 4].Text,
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 5].Text, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 6].Text,
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 7].Text, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 8].Text,
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 9].Text, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 10].Text,
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 11].Text, xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 12].Text,
                        xlRange.Cells[xlRow, 13].Text
                    });

                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


            string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Sheet1></Sheet1>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);
            XElement sheet1 = doc.Root;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                XElement rd = new XElement("rd", new object[] {
                    new XElement("id", row["id"]),
                    new XElement("name", row["name"]),
                    new XElement("last", row["last"]),
                    new XElement("phone", row["phone"]),
                    new XElement("refF", new object[] {
                        new XElement("adresse", row["adresse"]),
                        new XElement("citie", row["citie"]),
                    }),
                    new XElement("age", row["age"]),
                    new XElement("mp", new XElement("degree", row["mp"])),
                    new XElement("dpa", row["dpa"])
                });

                sheet1.Add(rd);
            }

            doc.Save(FILENAME);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: After debugging i found this problem:

System.NullReferenceException: The object reference is not defined to an instance of an object.
    to SAMPLE.Form1.button1_Click (Object sender, EventArgs e) in C: \ Users \ Ysf \ Documents \ Visual Studio 2015 \ Projects \ SAMPLE \ SAMPLE \ Form1.cs: line 129

line 129=   ds.Tables[0].WriteXml(save.FileName);

Comment: A DataGridView does not always have a DataSource.  You can load the DGV manually like you did in your code and not have a datasource.  So DataSet ds = (DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource; the DataSource is null.

Comment: So please what should i do as code for export button?

Comment: You have to choices 1) Instead of putting data directly into a DGV put data into a datartable.  The make table the DataSource of the DGV so my code works 2) Change my code to take data directly from DGV instead of from a table.

Comment: How can i change your code to take data directly from DGV?

Comment: Instead of enumerating through the datatable enumerate through the rows of the DGV.   Se : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487839/reading-data-from-datagridview-in-c-sharp

Comment: Unfortunately  I did not find a solution to this problem

Comment: I updated code to fill a datatable from the excel input.  You can then put into a DGV and output to XML.  It looks like you have 13 columns you are reading into the DGV but only 9 that are going into the xml.  So you need to adjust the columns names to be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much  sir The code works perfectly now  but there was a slight problem with saving the file in a specific path